# What does ['ReviewerProcess'] mean?

Tags: c#, json, populate

I'm watching a Pluralsight Course : Getting Started with JSON in C# Using Json.NET

I don't understand why its incrementing the processedBy Property

```
        public static void ShowPopulate()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("*** PopulateObject ***");

        //Generate test data
        List<UserInteraction> userLogs = GetTestData();

        string jsonReviewed = @"{
        'reviewed': true,
        'processedBy': ['ReviewerProcess'],
        'reviewedDate': '" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK") + @"' 
         }";

        Console.WriteLine(jsonReviewed);

        Console.WriteLine("- Populate values");
        foreach (UserInteraction log in userLogs)
        {
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonReviewed, log);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reviewed: " + userLogs[0].reviewed);
        Console.WriteLine("Reviewed Date: " + userLogs[0].reviewedDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Processed By: " + String.Join(" | ", userLogs[0].processedBy));
    }
```

Comment: That's invalid JSON because it uses single quotes and not double quotes.

Comment: It's incrementing the processedBy property and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The JsonConvert.PopulateObject takes an existing objects and amends its with the json data received.
In this example processedBy is a collection, and its adding 'ReviewerProcess' to the list.
The [] gives as an hint that an array or collection is being used.

You could look how the methods works here https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm

Comment: Where does ReviewerProcess come from?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.There is a count propertie and inside now are two things,ReviewerProcess is one of it